# Comparing two java objects on fly (data type not known)

Tags: java, compare, equals, oop

I need to compare different data objects.

Can any one tell me how can i do this. I don't know what are the data types i will get priorly. If i need to use any util from apache commons then please give reference to it.

At present I am using .equals() for comparing equality of objects .It is working fine when I am comparing quality for two strings. If i am comparing java.sql.date data type then it is showing unequal even though both contains same values.

Can any one suggest me on this regard.

Thanks,
Narendra

Comment: If you use java.sql.Date.equals( another java.sql.Date ) then the dates must be equal up to the millisecond. So they are not unequal when the same values (see getTime()) are used.

Comment: Besides overriding equals() method you can also take a look at Comparator interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it totally depends on the `equals()` method implementation of the object upon which you are calling the `equals()`  ,

Comment: I didn't know What is the data type I am getting at the time comparison.
But both objects are same data type. One contains new value and other contains old value

Comment: you can also use `instanceof` operator to make sure about datatype i mean class

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, the point of `equals()` method is to compare object values as opposed to reference comparisons using the `==` or `!=` operators.

In your example of java.sql.Date objects, the dates are probably not equal because certain parts of the time they represent are different - such as millisecond values - due to the level of accuracy.

In essence, it totally depends on the implementation of `equals()` on each object; I'd also stress that you may want to clarify *what* exactly you define "equal" to mean - the same type at runtime for instance or containing the same public field names described by some reflection on the objects - and then work from there.